# IE6/7 And ClassName (JS/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, xhtml, classname

I am trying to change the class of an element using javascript. 
So far I'm doing :

```
var link = document.getElementById("play_link");
link.className = "play_button";
```

***edit***: here is the actual code that replace the classname

In the HTML :

```
<a href="#play_link_<%=i%>" id="play_link_<%=i%>"onclick="changeCurrentTo(<%=i%>);return false;" class="play_button"></a>
```

In the Javascript
    function changeCurrentTo(id){
        activatePlayButton(current_track);
        current_track = id;
        inactivatePlayButton(current_track);
    }

```
function inactivatePlayButton(id){
    document.getElementById("recording_"+id).style.backgroundColor="#F7F2D1";
    var link = document.getElementById("play_link_"+id);
    link.className="stop_button";
    link.onclick = function(){stopPlaying();return false;};
}

function activatePlayButton(id){
    document.getElementById("recording_"+id).style.backgroundColor="";
    var link = document.getElementById("play_link_"+id);
    link.className = "play_button";
    var temp = id;
    link.onclick = function(){changeCurrentTo(temp);return false;};
}
```

with

```
.play_button{
    background:url(/images/small_play_button.png) no-repeat;
    width:25px;
    height:24px;
    display:block;
}
```

the old class is

```
.stop_button{
    background:url(/images/small_stop_button.png) no-repeat;
    width:25px;
    height:24px;
    display:block;
}
```

The context is a music player. When you click the play button (triangle) it turns into a stop button (square) and replace the function that is called.

The problem is that the class get changed, but in IE6 and 7 the new background (here /images/small_play_button.png) does not display right away. Sometime it doesn't even display at all. Sometime it doesn't display but if I shake the mouse a bit then it displays.

It works perfectly in FF, Chrome, Opera and Safari, so it's an IE bug. I know it's hard to tell right away from only these information, but if I could get some pointers and directions that would be helpful.

Thanks-

Comment: What are you using to trigger the class change?

Comment: I'm using onclick. Here is the tag and js call : <a href="#play_link" id="play_link"onclick="changeCurrentTo(1);return false;" class="play_button"></a>

Comment: I'm using an anchor tag because no other tag would work correctly with the onclick action in IE6, hence the return false hack.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the actual code that is being used to replace one class with another?

Comment: @Jon: I added all the code that is in the scope of this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create *one* image with a width of `50px` and a height of `24px` where you have both the play part and the stop part. Then you just ajust the background position like this:

```
.button
{
    background-image: url(/images/small_buttons.png);
    bacground-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 25px;
    height: 24px;
    display: block;
}

.play_button
{
    background-position: left top;
}

.stop_button
{
    background-position: right top;
}
```

Then you load "both images" at the same time, and no delay will happen when you change which part of the image gets displayed.

Note that I have made a new CSS class so that you dont need to repeat your CSS for different buttons. You now need to apply two classes on your element. Example:

```
<div class="button play_button"></div>
```

Comment: Ok I tried and the code is cleaner thanks to that.. and it now works in IE7 \o/. But I still have the same issue of disappearing background. Shaking the mouse bring it back ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setAttribute in your two funcitons. Try this out:
`link.setAttribute((document.all ? "className" : "class"), "play_button");`
`link.setAttribute((document.all ? "className" : "class"), "stop_button");`

Comment: FWIW, http://www.davidjrush.com/blog/2009/05/javascript-changing-class-names-to-alter-css/ mentions that IE occasionally decides not to execute setAttribute( "class", value ) correctly, so it may be necessary to call setAttribute( "className", value ) as well. (So four lines of code here instead of two.)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the exact markup, it's difficult to say, but the disappearing background image issue in IE is probably solved by adding a `position: relative;` declaration to the `.button` class and/or to its parent `div`.